# Préfixe r-/re-/ré- de répétition

Tags: orthographe, préfixes

Certains verbes prennent un *r* pour signifier la répétition (ex. : rajouter). Dans le cas des verbes qui commencent par une consonne, on ajoute un *re-* (ex. : reprendre, revoir, ...).

Pourquoi voit-on de plus en plus d'exceptions à cette règle de base, comme dans :

- réouvrir (pourquoi pas rouvrir) ;
- réapprendre (pourquoi pas rapprendre) ;
- réamorcer (pourquoi pas ramorcer) ;
- ...

Ces exceptions sont-elles correctes ?

Question bonus : l'Académie française s'est-elle prononcée sur le sujet ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

En gros, on ajoute *re-* devant une consonne et *ré* ou *r-* devant une voyelle (ou un *h* muet). Je pense que cette question porte sur le cas des voyelles, puisqu'il n'y a plus aujourd'hui de variation devant une consonne.

Je doute que l'Académie française se soit penchée ou se penche sur la question : *ré-* comme *r-* sont étymologiquement comme morphologiquement corrects, c'est donc à l'usage de trancher. La [Banque de dépannage linguistique](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1677) québecoise ne se prononce pas non plus : « On a la forme ré- ou r- devant un mot commençant par une voyelle ou par un h dit « muet ». »

Le [*Trésor de la langue française*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r-), qui est descriptif, a beaucoup plus de choses intéressantes à partager. Je me permettrai donc d'en citer les extraits pertinents. On pourra se référer à l'article pour une longue liste de cas attestés. Je me limite au seul cas de *r-* ou *ré-* suivi d'une voyelle, l'article comporte bien d'autres remarques intéressantes (notamment une analyse de la forme *ra-*, qui n'est plus productive mais survit dans des mots comme *raconter* ou *rafraîchir*).

> **Formes du préfixe** [Devant voyelle] En français contemporain, la forme du préfixe est *ré-* [ʀe]. Elle s'est substituée peu à peu à la forme élidée qui était encore la forme vivante au milieu du XVI<sup>e</sup> siècle devant *a-*, *e-*, *en-/em-*. Mais, comme les dérivés anciens se sont maintenus avec la forme élidée du préfixe, il en résulte une situation complexe. Le vocable existe tantôt uniquement sous la forme élidée : *rabaisser*, *raccompagner*, *rassurer*, *renvoyer*, *rouvrir*, tantôt uniquement sous la forme *ré-* : *réarmer*, *réassurer*, *réélire*, *réentendre*, *réinscrire*, tantôt avec les deux formes : *rajuster/réajuster*, *ranimer/réanimer*, *récrire/réécrire*. À un verbe de formation ancienne en *r-* peut corresp. un substantif dérivé plus récent en *ré-* : *ranimer/réanimation*, *rouvrir/réouverture*.

(Dans ce qui suit, « Est. 1549 » est le *Dictionnaire Francoislatin* de R. Estienne.)

> **Histoire — Morphologie** [Rattachement du préfixe à une base à initiale vocalique] Il y a des différences selon les voyelles :
>
> - Devant *a-*, le préfixe est élidé : une trentaine de vocables à la nomenclature avec seulement trois exceptions : *reajourner*, *readopter*, *reaggravations* [sic].
>   − Devant *e-* ou *es-*, le préfixe est élidé : *redifier*, *requiper*, *reschauffer*, *recreer* (et variante *rescreer*), *rescrire*, *reslire*, *respandre/repandre*, *respardre* (< espardre « il vient de *spargere* »), *respargner/repargner*, *respessir*, *resprouver* « esprouver de rechef », *ressayer*, *ressuyer*, *restablir*, *restancher*, *restreindre/reteindre*, *restendre*, *resternuer*, *restouper*, *restrangler*, *restrecir/retrecir*, *restriller*, *restudier*, *restuver*, *restuyer* (< *estuyer* de *estuy*), *resvanouir*, *resueiller*. On notera que la substitution de *e-* à *es-* pour noter [e], demandé par les réformateurs, reçoit dans Est. 1549 un début d'application au plan des entrées du dictionnaire. Mais, à une époque où la pratique du *é* n'existe qu'en finale de mot, cette réforme provoque une redoutable confusion pour les mots en *re-*: *reprouver* doit-il être analysé comme un dérivé de *eprouver*, forme modernisée de *esprouver*, avec élision du *e* de *re* ? ou comme un dérivé de *prouver* ? ou encore comme un emprunt *reprouver* (< latin *reprobare*) ? Il ne s'agit pas d'un problème d'école. Ainsi Est. 1549, à *recrier*, *recurer*, *reiouir*, renvoie-t-il à *crier*, *curer*, *iouir*, et non à *ecrier*, *ecurer*, *ejouir*.
>   − Devant *em-*, *en-*, le préfixe est élidé : environ quatre-vingt vocables à la nomenclature, pas une exception.
>   − Devant *im-*, *in-*, le préfixe n'est pas élidé : une vingtaine de vocables ; seule exception *rinser*, renvoyé à *reinser* (notre *rincer*).
>   − Devant *u-*, le préfixe n'est pas élidé : *reunir*.
>   − Lorsque la voyelle est précédée de *h*, la forme du préfixe est *re-*. Est 1549 en donne une liste de vingt-deux vocables. À *ra…* figurent *rabiliter* et *rabituer* avec indication des variantes *rehabiliter*, *rehabituer* et *rabiller* (sous var.). À *rha…* figurent des renvois *rhabiller* et *rhabituer* à *rabiller* et *rabituer*.
>
> En conclusion, vers 1530-50, l'élision devant voyelle reste donc la règle, sauf devant la série des mots en *im/in-* et quelques mots isolés en *u-* [y], et quelques emprunts savants en *a-*. Les débuts du développement de *re-* antévocalique datent de la fin du XVI<sup>e</sup> siècle, on en trouve trace dans le *Thrésor* de Nicot 1606 et dans Cotgr. [1611].

En conclusion, *ré-* est le préfixe productif moderne devant une voyelle, mais autrefois le préfixe était *r-*. Étant donné qu'il s'agit d'un préfixe très productif ([reconnu même par l'Académie](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/la-langue-francaise/questions-de-langue#56_strong-em-nombre-de-mots-de-la-langue-franaise-em-strong)), on ne peut pas dire que *r-* soit incorrect même pour une formation nouvelle.

Comment: Le ré- est quelque fois utilisé pour conserver la prononciation latine.

Comment: Une difficulté : *r**e**former*  : Former à nouveau ; et  *r**é**former* : Rétablir dans sa forme primitive (sens premier) suivi de trois autres acceptions, dont celle des militaires qui excluent de l'armée homme ou matériel.

Answer (score 4):

Le verbe rouvrir existe, et il est courant que 2 verbes coexistent et soient synonymes.
Exemples :

- [Rouvrir](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/rouvrir)
- [Réouvrir](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/r%C3%A9ouvrir)

Et mon dictionnaire de l'Académie française donne les deux comme étant valides.

Pareil pour *rapprendre/réapprendre*, par contre je n'ai pas *ramorcer* mais uniquement *réamorcer*. (D'ailleurs mon correcteur orthographique dans Firefox me souligne uniquement *ramorcer*)

À partir de là, le français étant une langue vivante, c'est le mot le plus utilisé qui restera. Il ne tient donc qu'à toi de faire perdurer les formules courtes si elles sont valides :-)

En revanche, je n'ai pas de règle à te donner à ce sujet, peut-être quelqu'un pourra nous éclairer sur ce point précis.

Comment: Je me réponds à moi moi-même avec ce lien qui visiblement contredit une partie de ma réponse : http://parler-francais.eklablog.com/rouvrir-reouvrir-a26639979