# Quand met-on un accent aigu sur le « e » dans le préfixe « re » ?

Tags: préfixes, diacritiques

Il y a beaucoup de mots français qui commencent avec le préfixe « re », mais quelques ont un accent aigu sur le « e », par exemple :

> Sans accent aigu: *repasser*, *retenir*, *ressembler*, *retourner*, …
>
> Avec accent aigu: *répéter*, *réitérer*, *réserver*, *réparer*, …

Est-ce qu’il y a un modèle pour ça ?

---

There are plenty of French words that begin with the prefix “re”, but some of them have an accute accent on the “e” – is there a pattern behind this?

*By the way*. Feel free to correct or improve my French (or English for what it’s worth)! (And I also appreciate comments explaining my mistakes.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Préfixe r-/re-/ré- de répétition](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7221/pr%c3%a9fixe-r-re-r%c3%a9-de-r%c3%a9p%c3%a9tition)

Comment: a partial answer is that you will write `ré` if the word after the prefix starts itself with `é` (unless there are some exceptions I missed).

Comment: @cram2208 Thanks for the link. Unfortunately, my French is not that good: As far as I understand it, the answer suggested is that *ré* is used before vowels. But I have listed three counterexamples to that rule and in that linked answer itself two further counterexamples have been used, viz. *réformer* and *résulter*. So while I see that this question is a duplicate, I wouldn’t have accepted the original’s answer – how shall I proceed?

Comment: @k.stm If you denote an accent in `réformer` is because `reformer` is a complete different word and it's simply to mark the difference and it's the only cases where exceptions arise to my knowledge.

Comment: @cram2208 Ah! If you update the answer in the linked question with that comment, that’d be great! (Then, this question is a total duplicate and I’m happy.)

Comment: @k.stm though your question seemed to be a duplicate, your accepted answer seems more accurate than the one received on the other question. Therefore, I would not maintain my duplicate flag. Seems I only got time to reply your comment when an answer was already accepted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On écrit ré- si le verbe commence par une voyelle (parfois en alternance avec r- seul): *réinitialiser, réanalyser, réécrire, réouverture* etc. C'est ce qui se passe avec *réitérer*.

Dans le cas des autres verbes que tu cites, **ce ne sont pas des construction employant le préfixe français re-**. Ces verbes sont des emprunts ou des descendants directs de verbes latins qui, oui, emploient le préfixe qui est l'ancêtre de re- en français, mais où il est désormais indissociable du reste de la racine, d'où son évolution phonétique distincte qui a donné *ré-* et non *re-*.

Le verbe sans suffixe n'existe d'ailleurs souvent pas (ou plus), le seul existant encore en français parmi tes exemples est *parer* et son sens est suffisamment éloigné de *réparer* (il signifiant à l'origine "préparer") que si on ajoutait *re-* devant, on dirait bien *reparer* ("décorer, orner à nouveau") et non *réparer*.