# Quelles sont les différence entre « amener » ou « ramener » et « apporter » ou « rapporter » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, usage, préfixes

D'après ce que j'ai compris jusqu'à présent, on utilise « amener » pour faire venir quelqu'un avec et « apporter » pour porter quelque chose avec soi.  Alors on ajoute un « r » à ces deux mots afin de signifier qu'on refait les actions que j'ai mentionnées.

Le problème est que des fois j'ai remarqué que les gens utilisent « amener » au lieu de « apporter », « ramener » au lieu d' « amener » même si c'est la première fois et qu'il n'y a aucune répétition (de plus, pour un objet)

Est-ce que ces mots sont interchangeables ?

Comment: C'est une faute de français que d'utiliser apporter à la place d'amener et inversement (même si 100% des français comprendront ce que tu veux dire si tu les inverses, car une grande majorité fait cette erreur). Le "r", est plus lié à l'endroit où se trouve la personne qui agit par rapport à l'endroit (destination) de l'action.

Comment: Il fait 3 ans que j'habite en France et je n'ai jamais entendu aucun français utiliser le mot "apporter". C'est toujours "ramener", pour les objets, ce n'est même pas "amener"  je commence à avoir honte d'utiliser "apporter"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On peut généraliser le concept d'amener qui se réfère à une personne :

> J'ai amené Claude à penser que le ciel est bleu
>   J'ai amené Paul à cette soirée.

Les personnes ont changé de position géographique ou d'opinion.
Tandis que

> J'ai apporté du vin à cette soirée
>   J'ai apporté mon chien

Mais on n'« apporte » pas sa copine : on l'« amène ».
Ramener ou rapporter suit une logique similaire, mais pour caractériser un retour :

> J'ai rapporté mon vin chez moi, car il en restait après la soirée.
>   J'ai ramené Paul chez lui : il était trop soûl pour conduire.

Comment: @Random Merci pour l'edition. Je suis sur mon téléphone, ces subtilités sont un peu plus délicates à gérer mais j'en prends bonne note pour mes futures réponses. Cela éclaircit grandement l'explication.

Comment: mais j'ai remarqué l'usage tel que ' Ce que vous pouvez ramener au Canada'. ici, pourquoi on a utilisé "ramener" même si c'est pas le cas d'un retour?

Comment: Amener ne se réfère pas uniquement aux personnes. En particulier, « j'ai apporté mon chien » ne se dit normalement que si le chien était dans ses bras, dans un panier, une cage ou équivalent. Sinon, l'expression correcte est « J'ai amené mon chien ».

Comment: @Thomson1 Je pense que la phrase 'Ce que vous pouvez ramener au Canada' s'applique sur des items obtenus à l'étranger que l'on apporte avec soi comme souvenir. On se retrouve donc dans un contexte de retour...

Answer (score 3):

**Amener/ramener/emmener/remmener** s'appliquent principalement aux êtres capables de se déplacer. L'idée originale est que le **meneur** se trouve devant une ou plusieurs personnes ou des animaux et qu'il les dirige, souvent avec autorité.

**Apporter/rapporter/emporter/remporter** s'appliquent au contraire plutôt à un objet inanimé que le **porteur** soulève et déplace.

La frontière n'est cependant pas aussi tranchée car il existe de nombreux cas d'utilisation où -mener peut s'appliquer à des choses, en particulier des véhicules et autres objets pouvant se déplacer sans être soulevés, et d'autres, plus rares où -porter s'appliquera à des êtres animés, mais surtout s'ils ne participent pas au déplacement (enfant qui dort, malade, etc.).

Les préfixes **a** et **em** indiquent le sens du déplacement, **r** indique que une répétition:

- mener/porter : pas d'indication du sens
- **a**mener/**a**pporter : vers le locuteur
- **r**amener/**r**apporter : une nouvelle fois vers le locuteur
- **em**mener/**em**porter : s'éloigne du locuteur
- **r**emmener/**r**emporter : s'éloigne une nouvelle fois du locuteur

La notion de répétition n'implique pas que le même objet, animal ou la même personne sont apportés/amenés une deuxième fois, mais simplement qu'il y a eu un mouvement d'aller-retour du porteur/meneur ou du porté/mené.

Answer (score 3):

Le préfixe [re-](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/re-) a plusieurs sens. Le sens le plus courant est « faire à nouveau », mais il y en a d'autres, en particulier celui d'un mouvement en sens inverse. Par exemple, un *retour*, c'est un déplacement vers le point de départ, pas la répétition d'un déplacement. Le seul sens qui soit productif en français moderne est « à nouveau », mais on trouve d'autres sens dans des mots qui existent depuis longtemps.

Les mots *[rapporter](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rapporter)* (*r-*¹ + *apporter*) et *[ramener](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ramener)* (*r-* + *amener*) ont tous les deux à la fois des sens où le préfixe signifie la répétition et des sens où il signifie un mouvement de retour. Ils ont de plus évolué un peu de manière autonome. Par exemple, *rapporter* peut signifier qu'on apporte l'objet à l'endroit où il était au départ, par exemple pour rendre un objet emprunté, ou rapporter un achat au magasin pour se le faire échanger ou rembourser. De même, un parent *amène* les enfants à l'école le matin (même si ce n'est pas le premier jour) et les *ramène* à la maison le soir.

En langue familière, on utilise des fois *rapporter* (ou *ramener*, voir plus loin) pour signifier *apporter*, sans qu'il y ait l'idée de répétition ou de retour.

> Tu veux m'emprunter ce disque ? J'le ramène demain.

Étymologiquement, *[amener](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/amener)* et *[ramener](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ramener)* sont dérivés du verbe *[mener](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mener)* qui signifie guider quelqu'un (ou quelque chose) qui se déplace tout seul, tandis que *[apporter](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/apporter)* et *[rapporter](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rapporter)* sont dérivés du verbe *[porter](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/porter)* qui signifie au départ que l'on tient l'objet. On dit quelque fois qu'on *apporte* quelque chose et qu'on *amène* quelqu'un, mais c'est une simplification, pas une règle absolue. Effectivement, on n'*apporte* pas une personne, mais *amener* est plus général, et en langue moderne est de plus en plus utilisé pour des objets qu'on porte. On *amène* un véhicule, une idée, …

En particulier, en langue familière, et de plus en plus même en langue soutenue, *ramener* peut signifier *apporter*. Le [*Trésor de la langue française* (ramener I.B)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ramener) indique

> Ce sens couramment utilisé dans la lang. parlée ou écrite est impropre selon certains dict. et certains puristes. On ne ramène pas une chose, on la rapporte.

Dans un devoir de français, il vaut mieux éviter de *ramener* un objet qu'on porte, mais dans la langue courante, ce n'est plus une faute, c'est un usage.

¹  <sub>sur la forme du préfixe *re-/ré-/r-*, voir [Préfixe r-/re-/ré- de répétition](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7221/pr%C3%A9fixe-r-re-r%C3%A9-de-r%C3%A9p%C3%A9tition).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Dans les expressions familières qui suivent, ces mots sont interchangeables.
Ce sont alors des nuances que l'on peut interpréter différemment, mais qui ne changent rien au sens de la phrase.

Le *r* insiste sur l'importance que l'on veut donner au verbe.

> Le voilà qui la ramène !

... « Le voilà qui *amène sa gueule* »" (et qui l'ouvre) en se donnant beaucoup d'importance : il s'affiche avec un ego sur-dimensionné, il veut se montrer et se faire entendre.

> Ramène ta fraise, y'a du nouveau à zieuter (à regarder).

... ramène a ici le sens de *reviens vite*.

*Amène ta fraise* est possible mais sera plutôt employé pour un premier contact, ou pour faire quelque chose de nouveau : « amène ta fraise, j'ai besoin de toi sur ce coup là »

> Youki, rapporte la baballe!

De son point de vue, le chien Youki va chercher la [ba]balle pour l'*apporter* à son maître, mais comme il le fait à la place de ce dernier cela donne l'impression qu'il la rapporte au point de départ (notion de retour du *r* ajouté).